# Applying script in subfolders

Tags: os.walk

I cd into a folder and start python. I want to apply a script to fix filenames in a directory and in sub folders.

```
import os

for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
 os.rename(file, file.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '_')
 print 'Processed ' + file.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
```

I get error "AttributeError: 'list" object has no attribute 'replace'. Help, please?

Answer (score 0):

os.walk returns a 3-tuple that includes the root directory of the script, a list of subdirectories, and a list of files. You unpacked the 3-tuple in the for-loop and you're calling replace on the list of files.

You may want something like this:

```
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
   for file in files:
      os.rename(file, file.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '_')
      print 'Processed ' + file.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
```

You want to iterate through the list of the files and do you "replacing" on those individual files.